# R linearHypothesis (car package) testing for superiority and not just equality

Tags: r, statistical-test, linearhypothesis

I'm using the `corrosion` dataset from the `faraway` package in R.
I have built a simple linear model using:

```
# Load the data
data(corrosion)
help(corrosion) # Display in the "Help" window some informations
head(corrosion)

# Simple linear regression
model <- lm(loss ~ Fe, data = corrosion)
summary(model)
```

One of the question is: "You want to test the null hypothesis that the same expected weight loss is equal to
95mg/dm2/day at 1.5% of iron content"

To answer this question I use the `linearHypothesis` function from the `car` package.

```
# H0: C*beta = rhs
linearHypothesis(model, c(1, 1.5), rhs = 95)
```

And it give me the p-value for this test.

**So, now my question is: if null hypothesis H0 is like: "weight loss of at least 95mg/dm2/day", how can I test it?**

In other words, the first question the equation of H0 was: *Hypothesis: (Intercept)  + 1.5 Fe = 95*
And now I want to test this H0: *Hypothesis: (Intercept)  + 1.5 Fe >= 95*

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think the `linearHypothesis` function does one-sided tests, but you can use the fact that in linear models, if the two-sided p-value is p, then the one-sided p-value is either `p/2` or `1-p/2`.  It is `p/2` if the estimate lies outside H0 and `1-p/2` if it is within.

Comment: You got a "close vote" because someone thinks this is more of a statistical question than a programming question.  I disagree, though my answer looks more like a statistical answer than a programming answer.  Maybe I should edit it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer based on `t_value <- summary(model)$coefficients["Fe", "t value"]` is incorrect.  That `t_value` would be used in a test of `H0: Fe = 0`, not in a test of `H0: Hypothesis: (Intercept) + 1.5 Fe >= 95`.

The difficulty here is that the `linearHypothesis()` function doesn't do one-sided tests.

One way to do the one-sided test is to use the relation between p-values of one-sided and two-sided tests that works in linear models when the parameter estimates have normally distributed errors.  The relation is as follows:

If the test of `H0: param = x` versus `H1: param != x` has p-value `p`, then the test of `H0: param >= x` versus `H1: param < x` will have p-value of either `p/2` or `1-p/2`.   It will be `p/2` when the estimate of the parameter is less than x, and `1-p/2` when it is greater.

In your case, the parameter is `(intercept) + 1.5*Fe` whose estimate can be found from `summary(model)` to be `129.787 - 1.5*24.02 = 93.757`, which is less than 95, so you should use `p/2 = 0.3097/2 = 0.15485`.

Edited to add:  The answer above is really an answer to the statistical question, rather than the programming question.  Here's how to do the programming:

```r
library(faraway)
library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'car'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:faraway':
#> 
#>     logit, vif

# Load the data
data(corrosion)

# Simple linear regression
model <- lm(loss ~ Fe, data = corrosion)

# Two-sided test of H0: (intercept) + 1.5 Fe = 95

test <- linearHypothesis(model, c(1, 1.5), rhs = 95)
test
#> Linear hypothesis test
#> 
#> Hypothesis:
#> (Intercept)  + 1.5 Fe = 95
#> 
#> Model 1: restricted model
#> Model 2: loss ~ Fe
#> 
#>   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
#> 1     12 113.45                           
#> 2     11 102.85  1    10.603 1.1341 0.3097

p <- test$"Pr(>F)"[2]
p
#> [1] 0.3097301

estimate <- coef(model) %*% c(1, 1.5)
estimate
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 93.75676

onesided <- if (estimate < 95) p/2 else 1 - p/2
onesided
#> [1] 0.1548651
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ok thanks, now I understand, so compare to the significance level (0.05), I can't reject the null hypothesis (H0) here, right?

Comment: Yes, you have observed something less than 95, but not so much less that it couldn't have arisen by chance when the true value is actually 95 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Adrien Riaux, One wayout could be...

First, extract `t-value` from your fitted model:

```
# Simple linear regression
model <- lm(loss ~ Fe, data = corrosion)
```

To test the null hypothesis H0: (intercept) + 1.5 Fe >= 95, we need to calculate the t-value using the estimated coefficients and their standard errors:

```
# first, extract the estimated coefficients and their standard errors
b <- coef(model)
SE_of_b <- sqrt(diag(vcov(model)))

# the, calculate the t-value for `(intercept) + 1.5 Fe = 95`
t_value <- (b[1] + 1.5 * b[2] - 95) / sqrt(SE_of_b[1]^2 + (1.5 * SE_of_b[2])^2)
```

And then, calculate the p-value:

```
# finally, calculate the 'p-values' (for the one-sided test where the 
# null hypothesis is '(intercept) + 1.5 Fe >= 95')

p_value <- pt(t_value, df = nrow(corrosion) - 2, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

Finally,

```
# if the p-value is less than 0.5 (significance level) and t_value is less than 0, 
# reject Null Hypothesis (H0), otherwise, we fail to reject H0

ifelse((p_value < 0.5 & t_value < 0), "Reject H0: loss is less than 95mg/dm2/day", "Failed to reject the H0: weight loss is at least 95mg/dm2/day")
```

Here, I am assuming the null hypothsis to be defined as:

```
Null hypothesis (H0): (intercept) + 1.5*Fe >= 95

and,

Alternative hypothesis: (intercept) + 1.5*Fe < 95
```

Let me know if this gives you some ideas...

Comment: I don't see the linear hypothesis being used anywhere in your answer.

Comment: @user2554330 - since OP asked for `So, now my question is: if null hypothesis H0 is like: "weight loss of at least 95mg/dm2/day", how can I test it?` I gave them work around... OP should modify their question to mention that they specifically want to use `linearHypothesis` function...

Comment: @ManojKumar, the point is that your code uses the t-value for the test of Fe = 0, not for (intercept) + 1.5*Fe = 95.